# Pass Laravel Route Variable into AngularJS Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

What is the best way to pass a Laravel route variable into an AngularJS controller or service?

For example I have a route of domain.com/contacts/87 where 87 is the contact's ID, this route shows the view/edit frontend for the Contact model with ID of 87. I want Angular to somehow get the ID of 87 to make a call to the RestfulAPI to retrieve a JSON representation of the Laravel Contact model, it will also be used for update and delete requests.

**Partial from my AngularJS Contact service:**

```
show: function (id) {
                var url = '/api/contacts/';
                return $http({
                    url: url+id,
                    method: "GET"                        
                });
            },
```

Comment: You mean to get Angular read the variable from the URL? or how do you reach this route?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer by passing in the ID using blade/php echo into the ng-init fore example:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="contactController" ng-init="init({{$contact->id}})">
```

*contactController partial:*

```
$scope.init = function (contactID) {
            if (contactID) {
                $scope.contact.id = contactID;
                $scope.showContact();
            }
            ...
        };
```

Please let me know if this is a valid/safe way of doing this?